# Checkbox Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I'm using angular and I'm not sure if problem is with it.
So I have a checkbox, and when I click on it, it works, but when I need to choose another object
and I need to click on it. It appears it (checkbox) has previous state.
I need that if I choose another element to click on. It has default state (which is untick (false)).

.ts

```js
show = false

toggleContract() {
   this.show = !this.show
}
```

.html

```html
<p-checkbox  (click)='toggleContract()' [ngModel]="show"></p-checkbox>
<ng-container *ngIf="show"><ng-container />
```

Comment: You can use `[(ngModel)]` for two way binding. You don't actually need the function since you bound the `show` variable to your checkbox

Comment: If I use two way binding it just can't be checked

Comment: Just remove the function and `(click)`  event handler from your checkbox

Comment: Sorry I read before it was eddied. Well I tried. I must also say that this checkbox affect if one div is shown or not, if I do like you said. The behavior stays the same/, and div appears once and stays shown no matter how many times I clicked

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add `ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}"` to your checkbox?

Comment: Tried the same result, it should look like that  ?   <p-checkbox  (click)='toggleContract()'[ngModel]="show" ngModelOptions="{standalone: true}"></p-checkbox>

Comment: yea but you need to use two-way binding like this ```[(ngModel)]```.

Comment: Show full code related to problem, on stackblitz e.g.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two way binding `[(ngModel)]` then you don't need to handle the event. Angular does itself.

HTML:

```
<p-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="show"></p-checkbox>
<ng-container *ngIf="show"><ng-container />
```

Typescript:

```
show = false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you are using PrimeNG - assumption made from p-checkbox**

For some reason it looks like primeNG has multiple values set as a default & is therefore expecting an array. Apparently you can pass `[binary]="true"` to override this functionality and bind directly to a single boolean.

```
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="show" [binary]="true"></p-checkbox>
```